# How to convert datatable record into custom Class?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have data table with following record

```
Columns -> A B C D E 
Rows->     1 2 3 X Y
           1 2 3 P Q
```

I would like this datatable to convert into my custom List as following

```
MyClass
{
int A
int B
int C
List<ChildClass>
}

ChildClass
{
String D
String E
}
```

I am using following code to make it but i stuck in between for childclass. Please help?

```
IList<MyClass> items = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
    new MyClass
        {
            A= row.Field<int>("A"),
            B= row.Field<int>("B"),
            C= row.Field<int>("C"),
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't quite follow the logic.  Why do you need both D & E in the child class?  If you do need them, why do you need a List?

Comment: In my real application, MyClass is my Custom Performance Category and Child Class is associated CustomCounters. So because one category can have multiple counters hence i need child class list. Similarly there will be multiple category. A, B, C feilds are the unique factors to decide new MyClass, it means if A,B,C having same value in datatable respective D, E coulumn valus should come with another child list. I hope i am clear now?

Comment: I think your database is not properly normalized. You should consider breaking the A,B,C grouping into its own table. (look up "database normalization" if you're not sure what I mean)

Comment: Your custom List code isn't valid. Inside `MyClass` you have a field of type `List<ChildClass>` that has no name. Also please clarify your expected output, given the input provided are you expecting a single MyClass with a list of 2 ChildClass?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx). Something like the following.

```
IList<MyClass> items = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
    row =>
        new
        {
            A = row.Field<int>("A"),
            B = row.Field<int>("B"),
            C = row.Field<int>("C"),
        },
    (key, values) =>
        new MyClass
        {
            A = key.A,
            B = key.B,
            C = key.C,
            Children = values.Select(row =>
                new ChildClass
                {
                    D = row.Field<string>("D"),
                    E = row.Field<string>("E"),
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

In your example, this will result in one `MyClass` object (with property values 1, 2, 3) with two `ChildClass` objects inside it (with property values X, Y and P, Q respectively).

Answer (score 0):

```
 xyz.Select(row=> new Class1
                 {
                     A = row.Field<int>("A"),
                     B = row.Field<int>("B"),
                     C = row.Field<int>("C"),
                     list = xyz.Select(row1=> new ChildClass
                 {
                     D = row1.Field<int>("D"),
                     E = row1.Field<int>("E")
                 }).ToList()
                 });
```

Suppose you have a list of data xyz. Try this it works.